# An error occurred while creating the driver. The device driver is not installed on any device, use a primitive driver if provided

Tags: c++, c, driver

I cannot create a kernel driver because of this error.
"The device driver is not installed on any device, use a primitive driver if provided"
It looks like my inf file contains something wrong, although I haven't changed anything.
Help me please)))

INF FILE

```
    ;
; hellodriver.inf
;
 
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=System
ClassGuid={4d36e97d-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Provider=%ManufacturerName%
DriverVer=
CatalogFile=hellodriver.cat
PnpLockDown=1
 
[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir = 12
 
 
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskName%,,,""
 
[SourceDisksFiles]
 
 
[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$
 
[Standard.NT$ARCH$]
 
 
[Strings]
ManufacturerName="<Your manufacturer name>" ;TODO: Replace with your manufacturer name
ClassName=""
DiskName="hellodriver Source Disk"
```

My driver code

```
[#include "ntddk.h"
 
 
VOID Unload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    DbgPrint("driver unload \r\n");
 
}
 
 
 
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;
 
    DbgPrint("hello\r\n");
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtaF6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In INF File, you have

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NT$ARCH$

Just keep
[Manufacturer]
and remove line there after.

Comment: I suggest you elaborate on your proposed solution and explain why it will work.