# Device driver does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if this is intended. [Security Certificate]

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wdk, windows-kernel, inf, driver-signing

I am trying to compile the XPSDrv Driver and Filter Sample from Microsoft Windows driver samples.
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/print/XPSDrvSmpl 
I followed the instructions step by step.

##### Solution Build Fails:

```
Warning     The driver package project C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\Driver Package\Driver Package.vcxproj doesn't have any references to other projects and no projects were packaged.
    Driver Package  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets   1710    
Warning 1324    [Version] section should specify PnpLockdown=1. package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   19  
Warning 2083    Section [printerpackageinstallation.x86] not referenced or used.    package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   70  
Warning 2083    Section [printerpackageinstallation.ia64] not referenced or used.   package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   78  
Warning 2083    Section [printerpackageinstallation.arm64] not referenced or used.  package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   82  
Warning 2083    Section [printerpackageinstallation.amd64] not referenced or used.  package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   74  
Error   1297    (NTarm64.6.0) Device driver does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if this is intended.  package (Package\package)   C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf   1
```

I referred to these two questions. But the answers don't work in my case.
[Device driver does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if this is intended in Visual studio 2019 for hello world driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197518/device-driver-does-not-install-on-any-devices-use-primitive-driver-if-this-is-i)
[An error occurred while creating the driver. The device driver is not installed on any device, use a primitive driver if provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63176819/an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-driver-the-device-driver-is-not-installed)
The solutions propose to either remove the INF file or Manufacturer section.
I am trying to set up a driver for a virtual printer (can't be a primitive driver) so a Security Certificate has to be generated (INF must exist) and the Certificate must have a Manufacturer.

##### xdsmpl.inf:

```
;
; Copyright (c) 2005  Microsoft Corporation
;
; All rights reserved.
;
; THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
; ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
; THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
; PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
;
; File Name:
;
;    xdsmpl.inf
;
; Abstract:
;
;    XPSDrv sample driver install file
;
[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Provider=%ProviderString%
ClassGUID={4D36E979-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Class=Printer
DriverVer=10/17/2008,6.1.6930.0
CatalogFile=XpsDrvSmpl.cat

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName%=Standard,NTx86,NTia64,NTamd64,NTx86.6.0,NTia64.6.0,NTamd64.6.0,NTarm64.6.0

[Standard.NTx86]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_PRE_VISTA

[Standard.NTia64]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_PRE_VISTA

[Standard.NTamd64]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_PRE_VISTA

[Standard.NTx86.6.0]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA

[Standard.NTia64.6.0]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA

[Standard.NTamd64.6.0]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA

[Standard.NTarm64.6.0]
"XPSDrv Sample Driver" = INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA

[INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_PRE_VISTA]
CopyFiles=XPSDrvSample,ConfigPlugin,COLORPROFILES
DriverFile=mxdwdrv.dll
PrintProcessor="MS_XPS,filterpipelineprintproc.dll"
ConfigFile=UniDrvUI.dll
HelpFile=UniDrv.HLP
DataFile=XDSmpl.GPD
Include=NTPRINT.INF, MSXPSDRV.INF
Needs=UNIDRV.OEM, XPSGPD.OEM, XPSDRV.OEM

[INSTALL_XDSMPL_FILTERS_VISTA]
CopyFiles=XPSDrvSample,ConfigPlugin,COLORPROFILES
DriverFile=mxdwdrv.dll
ConfigFile=UniDrvUI.dll
HelpFile=UniDrv.HLP
DataFile=XDSmpl.GPD
ICMProfiles=xdwscRGB.icc
CoreDriverSections="{D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F0},UNIDRV.OEM", "{D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F5},XPSDRV.OEM,XPSGPD.OEM"

[PrinterPackageInstallation.x86]
PackageAware=TRUE
CoreDriverDependencies={D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F0}, {D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F5}

[PrinterPackageInstallation.amd64]
PackageAware=TRUE
CoreDriverDependencies={D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F0}, {D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F5}

[PrinterPackageInstallation.ia64]
PackageAware=TRUE
CoreDriverDependencies={D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F0}, {D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F5}

[PrinterPackageInstallation.arm64]
PackageAware=TRUE
CoreDriverDependencies={D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F0}, {D20EA372-DD35-4950-9ED8-A6335AFE79F5}

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir=66000
COLORPROFILES=66003

[COLORPROFILES]
xdwscRGB.icc
xdCMYKPrinter.icc

[ConfigPlugin]
XDSmpl.ini
XDSmplUI.dll

[XPSDrvSample]
xdsmpl.gpd
xdnames.gpd
xdwmark.gpd
xdbook.gpd
xdcolman.gpd
xdnup.gpd
xdpgscl.gpd
xdwmark.dll
xdcolman.dll
xdbook.dll
xdnup.dll
xdscale.dll
xdsmpl-pipelineconfig.xml

[SourceDisksNames.x86]
1 = %Location%,,
2 = %Location%,,,x86

[SourceDisksNames.ia64]
1 = %Location%,,
2 = %Location%,,,ia64

[SourceDisksNames.amd64]
1 = %Location%,,
2 = %Location%,,,amd64

[SourceDisksNames.arm64]
1 = %Location%,,
2 = %Location%,,,arm64

[SourceDisksFiles]
xdsmpl.gpd                    = 1
xdnames.gpd                   = 1
xdwmark.gpd                   = 1
xdbook.gpd                    = 1
xdcolman.gpd                  = 1
xdnup.gpd                     = 1
xdpgscl.gpd                   = 1
xdsmpl-pipelineconfig.xml     = 1
xdsmpl.ini                    = 1
xdwscRGB.icc                  = 1
xdCMYKPrinter.icc             = 1
xdwmark.dll                   = 1
xdcolman.dll                  = 1
xdbook.dll                    = 1
xdnup.dll                     = 1
xdsmplui.dll                  = 1
xdscale.dll                   = 1

[Strings]
Location="XPSDrv Sample Driver Location"
ManufacturerName="VirtualPrinterABC"
ProviderString = "VirtualPrinterABC"
```

##### Output:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Driver Package, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Building 'Driver Package' with toolset 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0' and the 'Desktop' target platform.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(1710,5): warning : The driver package project C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\Driver Package\Driver Package.vcxproj doesn't have any references to other projects and no projects were packaged.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(1710,5): warning :
1>Inf2Cat task was skipped as there were no inf files to process
1>Done building project "Driver Package.vcxproj".
2>------ Build started: Project: package (Package\package), Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Building 'package' with toolset 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0' and the 'Desktop' target platform.
2>Stamping Debug\xdsmpl.inf
2>Stamping [Version] section with DriverVer=11/06/2021,2.57.51.890
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf : error 1297: (NTarm64.6.0) Device driver does not install on any devices, use primitive driver if this is intended.
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf(19-19): warning 1324: [Version] section should specify PnpLockdown=1.
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf(70-70): warning 2083: Section [printerpackageinstallation.x86] not referenced or used.
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf(74-74): warning 2083: Section [printerpackageinstallation.amd64] not referenced or used.
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf(78-78): warning 2083: Section [printerpackageinstallation.ia64] not referenced or used.
2>C:\Users\ihebb\source\repos\Windows-driver-samples-master\print\XPSDrvSmpl\install\xdsmpl.inf(82-82): warning 2083: Section [printerpackageinstallation.arm64] not referenced or used.
2>Done building project "package.VcxProj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```